# Select specific lines in a CSV file VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

This question is with relation to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48267951/revisions). After all, what was needed was to only remove trailing ";" on specific lines (1,2, last line and the line before that), so I wanted to know if there is a way to select lines in a CSV so that I can use my function on these specific lines.

What I have now and got as a solution of my previous question:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function RemoveTrailing(s As String) As String
  Dim nIndex As Integer

  For nIndex = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
    If Right$(s, 1) = ";" Then
      s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 1)
    End If
  Next
  RemoveTrailing = s

End Function

Sub ExportAsCSV()

    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Dim sFile2 As String
    Dim sLine As String

    sFile2 = Replace(MyFileName, ".csv", "SANS_VIDE.csv")
    Open MyFileName For Input As #1
    Open sFile2 For Output As #2

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sLine
        Print #2, RemoveTrailing(sLine)
    Loop

    Close #1
    Close #2
End Sub
```

What I need is instead of the loop :

```
Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, sLine
            Print #2, RemoveTrailing(sLine)
        Loop
```

Only apply the function "RemoveTrailing " on the first, second, the last line and the one before.

How can I do that? I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer I really had no intentions by writing "urgent" except describing the state of my problem, I had no idea that there was an issue raised to the matter so thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: It may be a cultural difference I/you have, but I tend to think of it as obviously unacceptable, since the only purpose of adding it is to hurry volunteers. I get your reply quite a lot, which is "I didn't know the rules". My response is always the same: there are some guidelines that should not need stating.

Comment: I respect your opinion but I think volunteers comment or answer a question because they want to help not because they are pushed or urged to do so.

Comment: We are in agreement then `:-)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by knowing how many rows are present in the file, so read it through first and count them. Then when you're writing them perform the `RemoveTrailing` if the row you're outputing is 1st, 2nd, penultimate or last..

Try this:

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()

Dim MyFileName As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Dim sFile2 As String
Dim sLine As String

sFile2 = Replace(MyFileName, ".csv", "SANS_VIDE.csv")

Dim rowcount As Long, thisrow As Long

Open MyFileName For Input As #1
rowcount = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, sLine
    rowcount = rowcount + 1
Loop
Close #1

Open MyFileName For Input As #1
Open sFile2 For Output As #2
thisrow = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    thisrow = thisrow + 1
    Line Input #1, sLine
    If thisrow <= 2 Or thisrow >= rowcount - 1 Then
        Print #2, RemoveTrailing(sLine)
    Else
        Print #2, sLine
    End If
Loop
Close #1
Close #2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is exactly what I was looking for